# Matlab array output from 'for' loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement

```
root=transpose([-10 2 20 -5]); 
wd_root=zeros();
for i = 1:length(root)
    if root(i)>0
    root(i)
    wd_root(i,:)=[root(i)]
    end

end
wd_root
```

This outputs the array as [0,2,20], but I am trying to output only array as [2,10]. I don't know why is it adding additional element '0'. Can anyone see a mistake?
Thanks

Comment: Because you assign do `wd_root(2,:) = root(i)`, which means that the second(!) value in the array gets the value 2. Your code is a little confusing by the way. To obtain what you need, just do `wd_root = root(root>0)`.

Comment: sorry! I am a beginning at matlab. thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: No problem :) I would advise you to really spend some time reading some introductory stuff of MathWorks.

Comment: as Jan de Gier mentioned, your problem can be solved in one line. +1